# Cannot call function from .kv file, interpreter claims class and method don't exist

Tags: python, kivy

When i run the file, the buttons show up. Everything looks fine, until i click button 1 for the method Main.c() to get called. the interpreter spits out an exception claiming i haven't defined it yet, when i have. I cannot find a solution anywhere.

the .py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


kivy.require("1.11.1")


class Main:
    @staticmethod
    def c():
        print("c")


class Start(App):

    def setup(self):
        Builder.load_file('start.kv')


Start().run()
```

the .kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: "Button 1"
        on_press: Main.c()
    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
        on_press: print(8 * 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code, but, one way to do what you ask for is to

- Create an instance of your `Main` class in your `App` class: `self.main = Main()`
- Call this instance from your `kv` code: `on_press: app.main.c()`